# Is there a way to enforce the simulation step to be smaller than a compile-time constant in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

**Question**

Is there a way to enforce the simulation step to be smaller than a compile-time constant in a simulink model?

---

**Context**

I'm trying to build a PWM block on simulink. As it is now, I have to make sure that the user chooses a step size responsibly (smaller than half the period chosen by him), otherwise the block behaves abnormally. The only way I came up was to stop the simulation if the step size is not small enough, but I find that very annoying (as a user). If possible, I'd like for the user to not worry about this at all.

Comment: Are you using a fixed-step or variable-step solver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do: add the following pseudo-code to the block callback `StartFcn`:

```
T_PWM = get_param(gcb,...); % get the block parameter (period) of the current PWM block (string)
T_PWM = str2double(T_PWM);
T_solver = get_param(bdroot,'FixedStep'); % get fixed used by the solver (string)
T_solver = str2double(T_solver); % convert from string to double
if T_solver > 0.5*T_PWM
   error('Solver step size must be smaller than half the PWM period')
end
```

Comment: Great idea, but how would I implement this in a library block?

Comment: Also, your solution does not corrects the step size to the right value, it forces the user to do that. Is there a way to correct it programatically?

Comment: Having a library block or not is irrelevant, because you are adjusting the model parameter (step size), not the block. You just need to specify the right path to the PVM block when calling `get_param`. If you don't know _a priori_ where the PWM block(s) is/are in the model, you may need to use `find_system` first.

Comment: I thought the onus was on the user to correct the step size himself/herself, hence the proposed solution . If you want to automatically change the model step size, then replace the `error` line by something like `set_param(bdroot,'FixedStep',num2str(0.5*T_PWM))`.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but from what I've understood about your answer, everyone that uses the PWM block from my library should add those lines of code to their model's callback function?

Comment: Yes. Because the potential problem lies with the model where the block is used, not with the block itself.

Comment: I agree with you, but isn't there a way to make the block fix the model step size? Or at least make the block send an error message like yours?

Comment: OK, maybe you can try putting the code in the `StartFcn` callback of the block, then the user wouldn't have to do anything to their model. See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/block-callbacks.html.

Comment: I was reading that exact page right now ^^. So I can do that even if the block is actually a library link, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I would test it though, to make sure it actually works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67006/discussion-between-h3now-and-am304).

Comment: Reference for future readers: This works for library blocks as well, I have just tested it in Matlab R2012b